# SNS認証を実装しようとDeviseに関するエラーについて教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

FaceBookのSNS認証を実装中で　rails s を実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:259:in `block in devise_for': Mapping omniauth_callbacks on a resource that is not omniauthable (ArgumentError)
Please add `devise :omniauthable` to the `User` model
```

何が原因なのかググってもよく分からなかったので解決方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/196085

Comment: @KazukiTomonaga さん、スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、一部でも良いのでソースコードを追記していただくことは可能でしょうか？　エラーメッセージだけだと原因がひとつに定まらないことはよくありますし、ソースコードが無いと回答者が問題を再現することができません。質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(\_ \_)>

Comment: 参考にしたページのURLなどを質問文を編集して追加してみてください。多分、何か作業手順を飛ばしているか、そのページに書かれていないかしていると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

エラメッセージにあるように

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :omniauthable
end
```

と`devise`のためのオプション`:omniauthable`を追加してください。

Comment: 無事解決できました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決できてよかったです。それではベストアンサーにチェックを付けて解決済みにしてください。そうすると一覧を見たときに解決済みかどうか他の人にもすぐにわかりますので。